# How to remove or customize opening the record from crm grid in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have my own entity.I am enable that for view in sales from customization.
Entity click will open page which has a grid and list of records.

My problem is that I don't want redirection for open that record.Or It is also fine if open my own webresource from record click is possible. So,Is there any way to remove that or customize that?

Below image shows briefly that actually where I get problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry but that's not possible in supported way.

Comment: Agreed.  Only supported option is to right-click and choose Open in New Window.  It's one of my biggest annoyances with CRM. :/